# simplxml_load_file performance issues

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm working on a system which pulls xml files from a remote location and saves them locally. Then the xml file is loaded and converted into an object that is an instance of `SimpleXMLElement` with `$xmlObject = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);`

This allows for calling this object's methods like `$xmlObject->xpath(..)` and implement required logic.

Unfortunately, the average size of every xml file is 14MB. `simplexml_load_file` is called on every page request. It takes approximately 6/7 seconds for a page to load making it very impractical to use.

To remedy the situation, I though I would serialize the `SimpleXMLElement`, save it to a file, and then unserialize whenever I need to make calls on the objects. To my surprise, PHP does not support serliazlizing `SimpleXMLElement`objects.

In what other way can I possibly address the issue of long page loads in this case?

Comment: If you're working with large XML files, then you really need to use a pull parser like [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php).... SimpleXML works well with small volumes of data (prefereably without namespacing), but not with larger volumes.... you won't be able to serialize with XMLReader either, but you should find it a lot faster for bigger data volumes

Comment: @MarkBaker if this was an answer I'd accept it :) XMLReader get the job done :)

Comment: *"14MB"* is not large for SimpleXML per se, perhaps for the xpath.((right, this then becomes your next problem [Selecting parent nodes with XMLReader](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29539526/367456)). I suggest you to metric first: Where are the 6-7 seconds spend? In the download, in loading the XML in running the xpath query? You need to first find out to better understand which problem you acutally need to solve.

Comment: @hakre I agree that profiling should be done first to effectively address the problem. However, not pinpointing with all certainty where the problem is, I managed to give the system a big speed boost by using `XMLReader` as per my other topic. I admit that I did it a bit blindly, but I was pressed for quick results so I decided to take a shot.

Comment: Okay, well, that acutally is good info. :)