# Selecting parent nodes with XMLReader

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I had to rewrite part of a programme to use XMLReader to select parts of an XML file for processing.

Take this simplified XML as an example:

```
<odds>
    <sport>
        <region>
            <group>
                <event name="English Championship 2014-15" eventid="781016.1">
                    <bet name="Kazanan" betid="12377108.1">
                        <selection selectionid="52411062.1"/>
                        </selection>
                    </bet>
                </event>
            </group>
        </region>
    </sport>
</odds>
```

This call to `xpath()`:

```
$bets = $xml->xpath(
    "//odds/sport/region/group/event/bet/selection[contains(@selectionid,'".$selectionToFind."')]/.."
    );
```

would select the whole `<bet>` node and its children (`<selection>` nodes).

My code, however, would select only one `<selection>` node with a given `selectionid`:

```
$reader = new XMLReader;
$reader->open('file.xml');

while($reader->read()) {
    $event = $reader->getAttribute($value); 

    if ($event == 781016.1 ) {
        $node = new SimpleXMLElement($reader->readOuterXML());
        var_dump($node);
        break;
    }
}
```

How can replicate the behaviour of `xpath()` with `XMLReader` so that I select the `<bet>` node and its children and not only one `<selection>` child?

I guess the question boils down to: Can I select the whole parent node `<bet>` by the attribute value of a child, e.g. `<selection selectionid="[some_value]">`?

Comment: 2 things. You actually have only one selection node in your XML. And second your code should select the 'event' note as it is in the moment, not the 'bet' node. The 'event' note has the 'eventid' attribute.

Comment: @YasenZhelev, sorry I've already intriduced an edit. In fact there is a varialble `$value` in my code. It is also encapsulated in a class method. I just reproduced simplified representations - same as the XML - it's much larger. I guess the question boils down to: Can I select the whole parent node `<bet>` by the attribute value of a child, e.g. `<selection selectionid="[some_value]">`?

Comment: OK, check my updated answer. I think it will help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ignore the SimpleXML solution and look down at the XMLReader one]

I would suggest using the SimpleXMLElement::xpath method.

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string);

/* Search for <a><b><c> */
$result = $xml->xpath("/odds/sport/region/group/event/bet");
```

$result will contain all children of 'bet' note.

// XMLReader solution **********************

```
$reader = new XMLReader;
$reader->open('file.xml');
$parent_element = null;

while($reader->read()) {
    $selectionid = $reader->getAttribute('selectionid'); 

    if ($selectionid == '52411062.1' ) {
        // use the parent of the node with attribute 'selectionid' = '52411062.1'
        $node = $parent_element;
        var_dump($node);
        break;
    }
    elseif ($reader->name === 'bet') { )
    {
        // store parent element
        $parent_element = new SimpleXMLElement($reader->readOuterXML());
    }
}
```

Comment: I could perform an `xpath()` query on `SimpleXMLElement` of the entire XML file. This, however, is not practical, since the XML file is 14MB. I resorted to traversing the XML with XMLReader to select only the nodes that I need, and only then convert the nodes into SimpleXMLElement. This is connected with the performance issues caused by loading the whole XML file as `SimpleXMLElement`.

Comment: Actually, `SimpleXML` should never be used when there are other XML libraries available, because it breaks down very quickly. XMLReader does not support XPath - why not simply use DOMXPath? See e.g. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xpathphp/.

Comment: Well, the question was for XMLReader. I used SimpleXML by mistake and left it as part of the answer only not to break the conversation.

Comment: @YasenZhelev thank you so much for  being so helpful, an upvote is definitely due. You code should, by all means, do the job, but apparently, PHP has trouble performing so many object-creation operations in a loop. I noted earlier that my source XML file is really extensive. That might be the reason why I experience the code exiting the loop prematurely. I tested it with different configuration. It traverses the XML DOM as expected, but has trouble with the multiple object assignement.

Comment: @YasenZhelev I just tested the code again and found that it would do the job if you change `$reader->readInnerXML()` itno `$reader->readOuterXML()`. Please amend it if you see it fit, and this will be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: No, problem. Sorry that I missed that. I have not run the code, I just wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

[`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) is said to be more robust than `SimpleXML` with respect to performance (it has other advantages, e.g. it can properly deal with namespaces). See for example [this IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xpathphp/) for a discussion of several XPath libraries in PHP.

I'm just curious if your performance issue would persist (or still be as severe) when using `DOMXPath`:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('sample.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$nodes = $xpath->query("/odds/sport/region/group/event/bet[selection/@selectionid = '52411062.1']");

foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
   print $xml = $node->ownerDocument->saveXML($node);
}
?>
```

The result, taking as input the small snippet you have shown, is

```
<bet name="Kazanan" betid="12377108.1">
    <selection selectionid="52411062.1"/>
</bet>
```

If that does not help, you really have to resort to an event-based (pull-style) XML parser, that does not read the whole document into memory - as Yasen suggests.

Comment: There is only one question. If `DOMXPath` loads the whole xml file into memory and behaves similarly to `simplexml_load_file` by performing operations on a `SimpleXMLElement`, then I will not be able to use it due to the performance hit. I've not tested this yet, but I sure will.

Comment: @luqo33 It does, but as I said, I'm curious if there are any differences between `SimpleXML` and `DOMXPath` in this respect - so please let me know as soon as you've had a chance to test it.

Comment: notice that I used `XMLReader` to traverse the file and then convert only the nodes that I need into `SimpleXMLElement` in order to perform further operations on them. I wanted to avoid loading the whole XML as a `SimpleXMLElement` object. So far I've managed to see that this method speeds things up by a magnitude. The problem is that `XMLReader`'s  node selection capabilities are not so robust as those of `xpath()`'s

Comment: @luqo33 Yes, I am aware of that - I also read your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

XMLReader can `expand()` the current node into a `DOMNode`. This will load only the node and its descendants into memory.

After that, you can use a `DOMXPath` instance or convert the node into a `SimpleXMLElement`.

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('data:/text/xml,'.urlencode($xml));

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

while($reader->read()) {
  if (
    $reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && 
    $reader->localName == 'bet'
  ) {
    $bet= $reader->expand($dom);
    if ($xpath->evaluate('count(selection[@selectionid = "52411062.1"]) > 0', $bet)) {
      var_dump($dom->saveXml($bet));
    }
  }
}
```

You will always have to decide which part to implement in XMLReader and which in DOM/SimpleXML. In XMLReader you will have to validate the nodes and maintain a state, but can avoid to load the data. At one point in the parsing the XML snippets will be small enough and you can use `expand()`.